# Appending to a recursive list in python

Tags: python, list, recursion

What I mean by "recursive" is something like this: `[["hello", world, [1, 2, 3]], ["foo"]]`. How would I append 4 to the `[1, 2, 3]` list?

I have the class:

```py
class RabbitHole:
    def __init__(self, new_name, new_holes):
        self.name = new_name
        self.holes = new_holes
```

(`holes` is a list of `RabbitHole` objects.)

I want to append to the hole `hat` that has the "path" (names of parent holes) `clothes/head/hat`. How would I change/append something to the hat hole while preserving the whole "directory tree" (I've done something like this in go but I can't figure out how to do it in python.)

Comment: How about making your class extend `dict` so you could do `clothes["head"]["hat"]["new_name"] = new_hole`?

Comment: how would I wrap this in a function that takes the format "clothes/head/hat", I don't think it's possible using this method

Comment: These solutions should help with that step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033549/nested-dictionary-value-from-key-path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969721/get-dictionary-key-by-path-string/47969823#47969823

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a multi-dimensional list per your example, you can do:

```
my_list = [['hello', 'world', [1, 2, 3]], ['foo']]

my_list[0][2].append(4)

print(my_list)
```

Which yields:

```
[['hello', 'world', [1, 2, 3, 4]], ['foo']]
```

Comment: read the full question. I need  to append to the RabbitHole class, only knowing the "path" I described